# Adaptive cards and missing binding properties in data

Tags: adaptive-cards

I'm building an adaptive card to show the response from a webservice. I have a textblock like so in my template:

```
 {
  "type": "TextBlock",
  "spacing": "None",
  "text": "${Omschrijving}",
  "isSubtle": true,
  "wrap": true
 }
```

When my data is like (abbreviated):

```
{
  Omschrijving: "hello"
}
```

The card shows "hello" in the textblock

when the data is empty string:

```
{
  Omschrijving: ""
}
```

The textblock does not show.

when the data is:

```
{
  
}
```

The textblock actually shows "${Omschrijving}".

I have no control over the webservice. Is there a way to do a null check or something in $when? I don't seem to be able to find anything.
Showing "code" when databinding fails seems to be a rather crude fallback to me.

Any solution possible?